# Magento 2 CLI doesn't work and frontend give error 500

Tags: magento2

suddenly my magento admin and frontend give me error 500. when I check using Putty, the command didn't return anything.

[image: putty]

[image]

as I remember, I didn't do anything for a while.
already tried to set file perms 755 for d and 644 for f, didn't work.
any solution? I'm very new to magento by the way. Magento CE 2.0.4

Answer (score 0):

please run the following command hopefully your issue may short out :

1) Go to your Magento project root directory.
2) sudo rm -rf var/cache var/generation var/di 
3) sudo php bin/magento setup:upgrade 
4) sudo php bin/magento setup:di:compile
5) sudo chmod 777 -R var/

After run these command you will be able to continue with your website.

Comment: unfortunately, didn't work. already using main account as admin. shared hosting fyi.

Comment: could you please check your error logs in that case ? you can run the following command if using apache2 : sudo tail -n100 -f /var/log/apache2/error_log hopefully you may get the error their.

Comment: these are the last 2 error logs (var/report) created on 14 June. [pastebin1](http://pastebin.com/P1Cd1DtD) [pastebin2](http://pastebin.com/ge5AzgJn) and there's no error logs created today.

Comment: i can't run tail -n100 -f /var/log/apache2/error_log from magento root/host root. there's no such file.

Comment: This is not necessary to be in root to the run the command hope you have HTTPd configured on your machine so you can run one of the following commands :  tail -n100 -f /var/log/apache2/error.log  or tail -n100 -f /var/log/httpd/error.log

Comment: will try again tomorrow, thanks anyway. I will contact my hosting provider since im soo new to this. thanks a lot. +1

Comment: hi @iPragmatech, i don't see any error log from cpanel or var/log directory, there's no file in it. is there any other approach?

Comment: if you have run the 5 command successfully and it is not working for you then you can restart your server using  "sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 restart" and then run your website i hope it may work for you.